# C: cross-platform RS-232 serial library?

Tags: c, cross-platform, serial-port, interfacing

I am looking for an open source cross-platform library for working with the serial port in C, something along the lines of the awesome [PySerial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PySerial) library (unfortunately I have to use C for this application).

I have only found this one: http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/, and that doesn't seem to have mention OS X compatibility.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You would think that a cross-platform C library for serial ports is something that would have existed for 20 years already, but as of 2013 there still wasn't one, so I created [libserialport](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport).

It is tested on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux (including Android), BSD and will probably build on other Unix systems also. It supports:

- Port enumeration (obtaining a list of serial ports on the system)
- Opening, closing and querying ports
- Setting port parameters (baud rate, parity, etc.)
- Port signalling operations (modem control lines, breaks, etc.)
- Reading, writing, and flushing data
- Waiting for events
- Obtaining error information

The initial 0.1.0 release is in active use by the [Sigrok](http://sigrok.org/) project for supporting serial hardware and is packaged in several Linux distributions already. The git version also includes new API calls for getting information about USB serial adapters (VID/PID etc).

Comment: Great except for gnu license

Comment: The license is LGPL. We took that decision specifically so it could be used in closed source projects too.

Comment: LGPLv2 would have been great.  LGPLv3 is too restrictive for embedded devices.

Answer (score 8):

This is a shameless plug, but I have a MIT licensed library for RS-232 communication which is portable to Windows and Linux and OS X here:

http://wjwwood.io/serial/

Comment: That appears to be a C++ library, not a C library. I can see exceptions in it.

Comment: It is c++, that's true. Perhaps, like @mark-rushakoff's answer about Boost ASIO, maybe it is still useful.

Answer (score 7):

I realize that you said C and not C++, but perhaps you could use [Boost Asio's serial ports](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html) and compile that into a library to be linked with your C application. It claims to be POSIX compatible, and OS X is POSIX.

Answer (score 6):

I released mine under the MIT license: https://github.com/Marzac/rs232

It is programmed in C and works well for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Comment: Really nice and clean.

Comment: Yes, nice and neat. Hit major dramas with occasional byte duplications and omissions on the rx stream though. Setting `c_lflag = 0` in `comOpen` magically fixed it.

Comment: There is a fork with additional features here: https://github.com/mrh1997/rs232/tree/add-features

Answer (score 4):

OS X supports the standard POSIX serial API, from `<termios.h>` and `<unistd.h>`.  Look up the functions `tcsetattr()`, `cfsetspeed()` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Get some additional OS X-specific Objective-C code along the lines of AMSerialPort, goSerial, serialconnect, PolKit, ... and implement a conditional compilation of your C source file.

http://osx.hyperjeff.net/Apps/apps?f=serial

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to keep it C only.